# Don't understand scope in python when using unittest

Tags: python, oop, python-unittest

I'm learning Unit test in python, but don't understand scope. I'm reading book, and saw example:

```
import unittest
from app.calculate import Calculate

class TestCalculate(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.calc = Calculate()

    def test_add_method_returns_correct_result(self):
        self.assertEqual(4, self.calc.add(2,2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

It is working fine. My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import unittest
from gif_grabber import *
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class TestGetRssXml(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUP(self):
        self.valid_url    = "http://animesquads.tumblr.com/rss"
        self.no_exist_url = "http://animesquads.sdfsdfsdf12=.com/rss"
        self.no_rss_url   = "http://animesquads.tumblr.com"

    def test_valid_rss_url(self):
        self.assertEqual(ET.Element, type(get_rss_xml(self.valid_url)))

    def test_url_unvaliable(self):
        #TODO check with no_exist_url
        pass

    def test_no_rss_url(self):
        #TODO check if url no rss
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run this test, I get error.

```
ERROR: test_valid_rss_url (__main__.TestGetRssXml)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gif_grabber_test.py", line 14, in test_valid_rss_url
    self.assertEqual(ET.Element, type(get_rss_xml(self.valid_url)))
AttributeError: 'TestGetRssXml' object has no attribute 'valid_url'
```

Why my variable scope similar with code in book example, but it doesn't work. Please help me find error, and explain where I make mistake.

Comment: This isn't a scope problem, just a simple typo; Python is case sensitive. I'd recommend you switch to an IDE (I like PyCharm, but YMMV) that can tell you when this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename `setUP` to `setUp`. Otherwise it won't get executed and `valid_url` won't be set (i.e. python unit tests will only call functions named exactly `setUp` before executing a test)

Comment: Thank you. I will more careful.